# Inner table content not aligned with outer table

Tags: html, css, html-table, border, cellpadding

I am creating a table inside another table. I have divided the columns to be the exact same ratio as the outer table. However, the columns are not aligned with outer table columns. Can anyone tell me what I am missing?

```html
<html>
 <div style="overflow:scroll;height:140px;width:100%;overflow:auto"  style="background-color:black">
  <table width="100%" style="padding:0; margin:0;"  cellpadding="0">
   <tr class="tbl_header"  cellpadding="0">
    <td width="3%">test1</td>
    <td width="7%">test2</td>
    <td width="3%">test3</td>                               
    <td width="12%">test4</td>
    <td width="7%">test5</td>
    <td width="10%"test6</td>                               
    <td width="7%">test7</td>  
   </tr>
   <tr  style="background-color:yellow">
    <td colspan="7" style="background-color:yellow">
     <div style="overflow:scroll;height:110px;width:100%;overflow:auto;border:none;background-color:green">
      <table width="100%" style="border:none;background-color:red" cellpadding="0">
       <tr class="even">
        <td width="3%">2</td>
        <td width="7%" class="tdAlign">Testing </td>
        <td width="3%" class="tdAlign">Testing </td>
        <td width="12%" class="tdAlign">Testing Testing Testing</td>                     
        <td width="7%">Testing_1</td>
        <td width="10%">Testing_2</td>     
        <td width="7%">Testing_3</td>
       </tr>
      </table>
     </div>
    </td>
   </tr>
  </table>
 </div>
</html>
```

Comment: You are setting width to `td` instead use `colgroup`

Answer (score 0):

When I inspect the table with chromes web kit. I see that the tables with 3% then they are supposed to be, because of the text length. U can fix this by adding `table-layout: fixed` to both your `<table>` elements.

If U want to use a table header I suggest using `<th>` ([see here](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_table.asp))

Answer (score 0):

```html
<html>
 <div style="overflow:scroll;height:140px;width:100%;overflow:auto"  style="background-color:black">
  <table width="100%" style="padding:0; margin:0;"  cellpadding="0">
   <tr class="tbl_header"  cellpadding="0">
    <td width="3%">test1</td>
    <td width="7%">test2</td>
    <td width="3%">test3</td>                               
    <td width="12%">test4</td>
    <td width="7%">test5</td>
    <td width="10%">test6</td>                               
    <td width="7%">test7</td>  
   </tr>
   <tr  style="background-color:yellow">
    <td colspan="7" style="background-color:yellow">
     <div style="overflow:scroll;height:110px;width:100%;overflow:auto;border:none;background-color:green">
      <table width="100%" style="border:none;background-color:red" cellpadding="0">
       <tr class="even">
        <td width="3%">2</td>
        <td width="7%" class="tdAlign">Testing </td>
        <td width="3%" class="tdAlign">Testing </td>
        <td width="12%" class="tdAlign">Testing Testing Testing</td>                     
        <td width="7%">Testing_1</td>
        <td width="10%">Testing_2</td>     
        <td width="7%">Testing_3</td>
       </tr>
      </table>
     </div>
    </td>
   </tr>
  </table>
 </div>
</html>
```

Looks like you missed a closing tag for a `<TD>`(`<td width="10%">test6</td>`). Hope this helps. Let me know